# Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

The readfile class is a class i made so i can read some strings from file.txt and then print them in the console:

```
   package mainpackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readfile {

    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
            try {
                x = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not find file");
            }

    }

    public void readFile(){
        while(x.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(x.nextLine()+"\n");
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }

}
```

But when i call the methods of the class in the main i get an error like this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. This is the call in main:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{


    readfile r = new readfile();
    r.openFile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile();


}
```

Any ideas? thank you

Comment: Besides the exception, does your console output happen to state "Could not find file"?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot about it too. It says could not find file and then Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mainpackage.readfile.readFile
 at mainpackage.CreateUsers.main

Comment: Well I'm too lazy to write an answer right now and don't want to write it in a comment but just think about that for a moment and you might come up with one yourself ;) (also i believe someone else will tell you soon anyway). Let's just say exceptions are there for a reason (mostly)

Comment: Actually im stuck in this thing for hours so can you give me a hint if you have an idea?

Comment: @MariosP you already have an answer with the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should not catch exception in `openFile()` or if catch it, throw new exception if you got exception in `openFile()` method Scanner will be null and in other method got null pointer exception.

```
package mainpackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readfile {

    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile() throws Exception{
            try {
                x = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //in here throw (this/another) exception to caller or don't catch this exption

                System.out.println("Could not find file");
                throw new Exception("Could not find file");
            }

    }

    public void readFile(){
        while(x.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(x.nextLine()+"\n");
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }

}
```

And main driver for testing:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try {
        readfile r = new readfile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("got exception");

     }

}
```

Comment: I use your code and when i run it types got exception but my notepad is not empty. Im new to java and i think i miss something easy but i still cant find it

Comment: Now you should got Exception with "Could not find file" message, and means the file not exist @MariosP

Comment: It has both messages:Could not find file
got exception

Comment: @MariosP and now that's means the file not exist ro not in place

Comment: i have a file.txt file in the bin folder of my project. Cant find what is wrong with it and i get this error message

Answer (score -1):

If exception is thrown, what value is under "x"?
What happend next?

---

(You should use debugger to check readFile() func)

**I need to clarify**: Questions were asked to make @Marios P sit up and think.

Comment: Then why do you ask `what value is under` haha. Why is this an answer at all? doesn't contribute anything, should be a comment.